# ¿Qué significa la expresión despectiva "pelo en pausa"?

Tags: expresiones, modismos, letras-de-canciones

Ayer me salió un meme viral que mucha gente se reía en donde una mujer le decía a otra de forma despectiva que "tenía el pelo en pausa". Me puse a buscar y no encontré explicación, pero sí encontré que hay hasta una canción con ese título "La pelo en pausa" (que no recomiendo escuchar). Qué significa exactamente? Es simplemente estar despeinada, o tener cierto corte de cabello, o estar peinado de cierta forma, o algún otro significado?

Comment: Ayudaría un poco de contexto respecto al meme. Soi una tenía un peinado muy raro puede ser que pareciese que lo tenía "en pausa" como cuando parar un vídeo y algo que estaba en movimiento se quede en una pose rara, innatural, solo porque el efecto de la pausa hace que lo veamos de una manera que es imposible verlo en vivo. Normalmente "estar en pausa" es "estar parado". También es probable que sea un regionalismo. El meme que leíste, parecía usar "español neutral" o ser de uan región particular?

Comment: Lo busqué. Madre santa. Si estamos hablando de Argentina, como sospecho, se puede/debería añadir "argentina" a los tags y aclarar que viene de ahí. Y si hay una imagen del meme o links a la canción, aunque no sea algo agradable de oír, adelante, todo ayuda.

Comment: @pablodf76 - Ahora que se abrió un bounty, tengo que preguntar, ¿por qué no se recomienda escuchar?  ¿La letra es grosera, las imágenes son ofensivas, la música está mal hecha, o qué?

Comment: @aparente001 No es un detalle en particular sino la impresión completa que provoca. De todas formas, sobre gustos no hay nada escrito.

Comment: @pablodf76 - O sea, si a alguien le diera asco, ¿por cuál aspecto sería?  Yo soy alguien se se asquea fácilmente.  Gracias.

Comment: @aparente001 No creo que te dé asco. Es una canción de lo que se llama en Argentina "cumbia villera", que imita y exagera rasgos del habla de las "villas miseria" (what in Brazil are termed *favelas*) y está repleta de alusiones a suciedad, etc. La canción básicamente se trata de insultar y degradar a una mujer por su aspecto.

Comment: @pablodf76 - ¿Por qué no me va a dar asco el sexismo, la pobreza, y la suciedad?  Gracias, de verdad.  Ahora puedo contestar sin tener que mirar más.

Comment: No me consta que la palabra se use solo en Argentina. Por cierto, muchas palabras que se usan en Argentina se usan también en Uruguay, por algo hay un dialecto  "español rioplatense" (Argentina+Uruguay) así que faltaría un nuevo tag

Comment: Por cierto, de esto vi una explicación en una cuenta de ask (que irónicamente no recuerdo ni la explicacion ni la cuenta) pero por el tipo de fuente no daba para publicarlo , aunque capaz era la explicacion correcta

Comment: Pablo, hay un post en Meta donde puedes proponer el tag: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2962/9385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**en pausa**

Lamentablemente no encontré una definición de diccionario.  Es equivalente a "en espera" y "on hold" (inglés).  [DLE define "en espera" así](https://dle.rae.es/?id=GYRO3eO%7CGYRrmid): *En observación, esperando algo*, lo cual no ayuda mucho.  Voy a dar mi propia explicación.  Si llamas a una oficina y el sistema te pone en una cola para esperar tu turno, o si contesta un dependiente que te pide esperar "un momento" -- que puede ser diez minutos o más -- describes tu actividad, con el teléfono en el oído, esperando quién sabe cuánto tiempo, así:  *Estoy en espera.*

No sé si "en pausa" se usa para la situación del teléfono, pero sí verifiqué que se usa en general.  Ejemplo tomado de [linguee.com](https://www.linguee.com/english-spanish/search?source=auto&query=%22en%20pausa%22):

> Por ahora, el Gobierno puso el plan en pausa.  | *For now, the government has put the plan on hold.* (inglés)

Ahora hay que agregar el pelo.  Daré un ejemplo del inglés, tomado de un [blog sobre cuestiones de peluquería](https://thisorganicgirl.com/my-nontoxic-hair-game/), con mi propia traducción:

> when I decide to straighten my hair I love wrapping it in this towel, perfect size, super light and I can keep it on and run around the house doing housework while putting my hair on hold until I can get to it.
>
> *... [con esta toalla ligera] puedo limpiar la casa mientras mi pelo está en pausa.*

Así que ***pelo en pausa*** significa que la persona no ha tenido tiempo de arreglarse el pelo.

Answer (score 3):

Pelo en pausa se le dice a las personas con el cabello duro por la suciedad. Que no se bañan muy seguido.

Comment: !Hola Julio, gracias por tu contribución y bienvenido al sitio de Español de StackExchange¡

 Ten en cuenta que puedes editar o ampliar la respuesta en cualquier momento para que se la califica mejor y sirva a quienes la lean.